# MVC nested views in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I'm developing a Java GUI program using JavaFX that consists of the player's hand, the board, and some cards. I'm trying to follow MVC patterns, but can't figure out how to properly nest views.

Specifically, I want three separate MVCs for the player, board, and cards. Such that when the card is played from the player's hand, to a node on the board, I want the view of the card to also transfer from the player hand's view, to the board node's view.

As for why I have MVC for cards, the cards can have variable properties such as hit points, and different methods for drawing the view.

Is the following code snippet going in the correct direction?

```java
class Player {
  ArrayList<Card> cards;
}
class PlayerView extends Pane {
  // Draw cards in players hand
  public void draw(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    for (Card card : cards) {
      // JavaFX method for nesting panes (views)
      getChildren().add(card.cardController.cardView); // <-- is this MVC valid?
    }
  }
}
class PlayerController {
  Player player;
  PlayerView playerView;

  public void update() {
    playerView.draw(player.cards);
  }
}

abstract class Card {
  CardController cardController;
}
abstract class CardView extends Pane {
  CardController cardController;
}
abstract class CardController {
  Card card
  CardView cardView
}

class CardA extends Card {}
class CardViewA extends CardView {}
class CardControllerA extends CardController {}

//etc...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models should not have references to controllers, as your `Card` class does. There are several variants of MVC (which is a pretty loosely defined pattern), but typically either the controller or the view will register with the model for updates when the data in the model changes. You could do this pretty easily if you used a JavaFX `ObservableList<Card>`.

I tend to interpret plain MVC as the view observing the model, and the controller invoking methods on the model to update it.

So I would probably do something like

```
abstract class Card {
    // properties...
}
```

---

```
public class Player {

    private final ObservableList<Card> cards ;

    public ObservableList<Card> getCards() {
        return cards ;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PlayerView extends Pane {

    private final PlayerController controller ;

    private final Player player ;

    private final Map<Card, CardView> cardViewLookup ;

    public PlayerView(Player player) {
        this.player = player ;
        this.controller = new PlayerController(player);

        cardViewLookup = new HashMap<>();
        player.getCards().forEach(this::cardAdded);

        // update card views when player's list of cards changes:
        player.getCards().addListener((Change<? extends Card> c) -> {
            while (c.next())  {
                if (c.wasAdded()) {
                    c.getAddedSubList().forEach(this::cardAdded);
                } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                    c.getRemoved().forEach(this::cardRemoved);
                }
            }
        });

        // register event handlers which will invoke methods on controller...

    }

    private final void cardAdded(Card card) {
        CardView cardView = new CardView(card) ;
        cardViewLookup.put(card, cardView);
        getChildren().add(cardView);
    }

    private final void cardRemoved(Card card) {
        getChildren().remove(cardViewLookup.get(card));
        cardViewLookup.remove(card);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CardView extends Pane {

    private final CardController controller ;
    private final Card card ;

    public CardView(Card card) {
        this.card = card ;
        this.controller = new CardController(card);

        // layout, register listeners with card, register event handlers...
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I have unique card views per unique card? Say I wanted sub classes `CardA` and `CardB`, and respectively `CardViewA` and `CardViewB`?

In your example if I called  `cardAdded(new CardA());`, wouldn't it would call the super class constructor of `CardView(Card card)`? When  I would wanted to call the sub class constructor of `CardViewA(CardA card)`.

Is there anyway to do this without a big if else statement `if (Card instanceof CardA) {} else if (Card instanceof CardB) {}` etc.? This is what originally made me try to tie the model and controller together.